# How to interpolate heatmaps (with nonuniform pixels) to draw contour plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, contour

I have data that I have been able to plot using heatmaps with nonuniform pixel sizes, [using the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002518/irregularly-spaced-heatmap). I'm now wondering what would be the best way to go about interpolating the heatmap and drawing a contour plot at a given value. Essentially, imagine if I wanted to draw a smooth curve on the plot generated in the linked question, corresponding to a value of `0.5`. One way of going about this could be to fit the data to a 3d spline. Each pixel in the heatmap also has an error estimate. It would also be great if I could use this information in drawing the contour map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of interpolating `pcolormesh`, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822925/how-to-smooth-by-interpolation-when-using-pcolormesh) gives a couple of options. I chose to go with passing `shading='gouraud'` as argument to `pcolormesh`.

When it comes to plotting a contour plot at `0.5`, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389363/plotting-contours-over-pcolormesh-data) useful. Pretty much using `coutour` the same way you would with `imshow`.

See code from the SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002518/irregularly-spaced-heatmap) linked in your question adapted to my understanding of what you are trying to achieve:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

bounds1 = [  0. , 3. , 27.25 , 51.5  , 75.75 , 100.  ]
bounds2 = [   0. , 127.,  165.,  334. , 522. , 837., 1036., 1316., 1396., 3000]
matrix = [[0.3    , 0.5    , 0.7    , 0.9    , 1.    ,  0.9    , 0.7    , 0.4  ,   0.3    , 0.3    ],
          [0.22725, 0.37875, 0.53025, 0.68175, 0.7575,  0.68175, 0.53025, 0.303,   0.22725, 0.22725],
          [0.1545 , 0.2575 , 0.3605 , 0.4635 , 0.515 ,  0.4635 , 0.3605 , 0.206,   0.1545 , 0.1545 ],
          [0.08175, 0.13625, 0.19075, 0.24525, 0.2725,  0.24525, 0.19075, 0.109,   0.08175, 0.08175],
          [0.009  , 0.015  , 0.021  , 0.027  , 0.03  ,  0.027  , 0.021  , 0.012,   0.009  , 0.009  ],
          [0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.    ,  0.     , 0.     , 0.   ,   0.     , 0.     ]]
x2 = np.array([1.7765000e+00, 3.9435000e+00, 4.5005002e+00, 4.5005002e+00, 5.0325003e+00, 6.0124998e+00, 7.0035005e+00, 8.5289993e+00, 1.0150000e+01, 1.1111500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.3665500e+01, 1.4780001e+01, 1.5908000e+01, 1.7007000e+01, 1.8597000e+01, 2.0439001e+01, 2.2047001e+01, 2.4724501e+01, 2.7719501e+01, 3.0307501e+01, 3.3042500e+01, 3.6326000e+01, 3.8622997e+01, 4.1292500e+01, 4.4293495e+01, 4.7881500e+01, 5.1105499e+01, 5.3708996e+01, 5.6908497e+01, 5.9103497e+01, 6.1926003e+01, 6.6175499e+01, 6.9841499e+01, 7.3534996e+01, 7.8712997e+01, 8.3992500e+01, 8.7227493e+01, 9.1489487e+01, 9.6500992e+01, 1.0068549e+02, 1.0625399e+02, 1.1245149e+02, 1.1828050e+02, 1.2343950e+02, 1.2875299e+02, 1.3531699e+02, 1.4146500e+02, 1.4726399e+02, 1.5307101e+02, 1.5917000e+02, 1.6554350e+02, 1.7167050e+02, 1.7897350e+02, 1.8766650e+02, 1.9705751e+02, 2.0610300e+02, 2.1421350e+02, 2.2146150e+02, 2.2975949e+02, 2.3886848e+02, 2.4766153e+02, 2.5618802e+02, 2.6506250e+02, 2.7528250e+02, 2.8465201e+02, 2.9246451e+02, 3.0088300e+02, 3.1069800e+02, 3.2031000e+02, 3.2950650e+02, 3.3929001e+02, 3.4919598e+02, 3.5904755e+02, 3.6873303e+02, 3.7849451e+02, 3.8831549e+02, 3.9915201e+02, 4.1044501e+02, 4.2201651e+02, 4.3467300e+02, 4.4735904e+02, 4.5926651e+02, 4.7117001e+02, 4.8231406e+02, 4.9426105e+02, 5.0784149e+02, 5.2100049e+02, 5.3492249e+02, 5.4818701e+02, 5.6144202e+02, 5.7350153e+02, 5.8634998e+02, 5.9905096e+02, 6.1240802e+02, 6.2555353e+02, 6.3893542e+02, 6.5263202e+02, 6.6708154e+02, 6.8029950e+02, 6.9236456e+02, 7.0441150e+02, 7.1579163e+02, 7.2795203e+02, 7.4106995e+02, 7.5507953e+02, 7.6881946e+02, 7.8363702e+02, 7.9864905e+02, 8.1473901e+02, 8.3018762e+02, 8.4492249e+02, 8.6007306e+02, 8.7455353e+02, 8.8938556e+02, 9.0509601e+02, 9.2196307e+02, 9.3774091e+02, 9.5391345e+02, 9.7015198e+02, 9.8671466e+02, 1.0042726e+03, 1.0209606e+03, 1.0379355e+03, 1.0547625e+03, 1.0726985e+03, 1.0912705e+03, 1.1100559e+03, 1.1288949e+03, 1.1476450e+03, 1.1654260e+03, 1.1823262e+03, 1.1997356e+03, 1.2171041e+03, 1.2353951e+03, 1.2535184e+03, 1.2718250e+03, 1.2903676e+03, 1.3086545e+03, 1.3270005e+03, 1.3444775e+03, 1.3612805e+03, 1.3784171e+03, 1.3958615e+03, 1.4131825e+03, 1.4311034e+03, 1.4489685e+03, 1.4677334e+03, 1.4869026e+03, 1.5062087e+03, 1.5258719e+03, 1.5452015e+03, 1.5653271e+03, 1.5853635e+03, 1.6053860e+03, 1.6247255e+03, 1.6436824e+03, 1.6632330e+03, 1.6819221e+03, 1.7011276e+03, 1.7198782e+03, 1.7383060e+03, 1.7565670e+03, 1.7749023e+03, 1.7950280e+03, 1.8149988e+03, 1.8360586e+03, 1.8572985e+03, 1.8782219e+03, 1.8991390e+03, 1.9200371e+03, 1.9395586e+03, 1.9595035e+03, 1.9790668e+03, 1.9995455e+03, 2.0203715e+03, 2.0416791e+03, 2.0616587e+03, 2.0819294e+03, 2.1032202e+03, 2.1253989e+03, 2.1470112e+03, 2.1686660e+03, 2.1908926e+03, 2.2129436e+03, 2.2349995e+03, 2.2567026e+03, 2.2784224e+03, 2.2997925e+03, 2.3198750e+03, 2.3393770e+03, 2.3588149e+03, 2.3783970e+03, 2.3988135e+03, 2.4175618e+03, 2.4363840e+03, 2.4572385e+03, 2.4773455e+03, 2.4965142e+03, 2.5157107e+03, 2.5354666e+03, 2.5554331e+03, 2.5757551e+03, 2.5955181e+03, 2.6157085e+03, 2.6348906e+03, 2.6535190e+03, 2.6727512e+03, 2.6923147e+03, 2.7118843e+03])
x1 = np.array([28.427988, 28.891748, 30.134018, 29.833858, 30.540195, 31.762226, 32.163025, 31.623648, 31.964993, 32.73733, 32.562325, 32.89953, 33.064743, 32.76882, 32.1024, 32.171394, 33.363426, 34.328148, 36.24527, 35.877434, 35.29762, 35.193832, 35.61119, 36.50994, 35.615444, 35.2758, 34.447975, 34.183205, 35.781815, 35.510662, 35.277668, 35.26543, 34.944313, 35.301414, 34.63578, 34.36223, 35.496872, 35.488243, 35.494583, 35.21087, 34.275524, 33.945126, 33.63986, 33.904293, 33.553017, 34.348408, 33.84105, 32.8437, 32.19287, 31.688663, 32.035015, 31.641226, 31.138266, 30.629492, 30.111526, 29.571909, 29.244211, 28.42031, 27.908197, 27.316568, 26.909412, 25.928982, 25.03047, 24.354822, 23.54626, 22.88031, 23.000391, 22.300774, 21.988918, 21.467094, 21.730871, 23.060678, 22.910374, 24.45383, 23.610855, 24.594006, 24.263508, 25.077124, 23.9773, 22.611958, 21.88306, 21.014484, 19.674965, 18.745205, 20.225956, 19.433172, 19.451014, 18.264421, 17.588757, 16.837574, 17.252535, 18.967127, 19.111462, 19.90994, 19.15653, 18.49522, 17.376019, 17.35794, 16.200405, 17.9445, 18.545986, 17.69698, 20.665318, 20.90071, 20.32658, 21.27805, 21.145922, 19.32898, 19.160307, 18.60541, 18.902897, 18.843922, 17.890692, 18.197395, 17.662706, 18.578962, 18.898802, 18.435923, 17.644451, 16.393314, 15.570944, 16.779602, 15.74104, 15.041967, 14.544464, 15.014386, 14.156769, 13.591232, 12.386208, 11.133551, 10.472783, 9.7923355, 10.571391, 11.245247, 10.063455, 10.742685, 8.819294, 8.141182, 6.9487176, 6.3410373, 7.033326, 6.5856943, 6.0214376, 6.6087174, 9.583405, 9.4608135, 9.183213, 10.673293, 9.477165, 8.667246, 7.3392615, 6.2609572, 5.5752296, 4.4312773, 4.0997415, 4.127005, 4.072541, 3.5704772, 2.7370691, 2.3750854, 2.0708292, 3.4086852, 3.8237891, 3.9072614, 3.1760776, 2.4963813, 1.5232614, 0.931248, 0.49159998, 0.21676798, 0.874704, 2.0560641, 1.5494559, 3.0944476, 2.6151357, 2.7285278, 3.4450078, 3.4614875, 5.779072, 8.063728, 7.7077436, 7.8576636, 7.4494233, 6.5933595, 6.1667037, 4.9452477, 5.6894236, 6.0578876, 5.9922714, 5.060448, 6.074832, 6.7870073, 5.7388477, 5.8681116, 4.7604475, 4.2740316, 3.785328, 4.060576, 4.9203672, 5.355184, 4.793792, 3.8007674, 3.6115997, 2.7794237, 2.5385118, 5.1410074, 5.5506234, 7.638063, 7.512544, 6.617264, 6.5637918, 6.452815])

# define colormap
N = 5  # number of desired color bins
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn_r', N)

# define the bins and normalize
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, N + 1)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
colormesh = ax.pcolormesh(bounds2, bounds1, matrix, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, linewidths=0.1,shading='gouraud')
cs = plt.contour(bounds2,bounds1, matrix, [0.5], colors='k')
ax.clabel(cs, cs.levels)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', rotation=50)
ax.set_xticks(bounds2)
ax.set_yticks(bounds1)
cbar = fig.colorbar(colormesh, ax=ax)
cbar.set_ticks(bounds)
ax.plot(x2, x1, color='black', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify something here, the contour plot is plotted from the heatmap without interpolation. The `gouraud` interpolation is only for aesthetic purposes here. Since the arguments passed to `contour` are: `plt.contour(bounds2,bounds1, matrix, [0.5], colors='k')`. If you want to apply `contour` to the interpolated matrix, you will have to do the interpolation (with `scipy.interpolate` for instance (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822925/how-to-smooth-by-interpolation-when-using-pcolormesh))) before calling `pcolormesh`  and `contour`.

Comment: If this approach doesn't quite address what you are looking for feel free to unaccept the answer to get more suggestions from the community